# I am not able to see the Suite pages on the Front page for Fitnesse tool

Tags: fitnesse, test-suite

I am very new to Fitnesse tool. So when I am creating Suite pages it is not getting displayed on Front Page. Can you let me know where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Suites are not 'magically' displayed. They show up on a page when an explicit link to them is added on that page, or when they are 'below' another suite page and that page has a `!contents` tag to display a list of its children.

Normally:

- when you add a suite it is not below FrontPage, but below the 'root' (e.g. 'MyTests' added does not end up in 'FrontPage/MyTests')
- FrontPage does not have a `!contents` tag in it.

My approach usually is to add a single suite which will be the parent of all my tests/suites and add a link to that page (manually) to the FrontPage.